# Why does wind direction change in a front?

Tags: meteorology, wind

Plenty of answers answer the question *that* it happens but I can't find a good answer as to *why* the wind shifts during the passing of a front.
For an extreme example see:
[image: a graph of an abrubt wind shift]

(in Dutch, x is hours and y is wind direction in degrees)
Where a passing cold front moved the wind directon from south to northwest.

The other question provides a very broad answer as to why wind changes *in general* and the answers there are applicable *in general*. My question is about the specific circumstances of a thermal front and what causes the change in the balance of forces to suddenly allow or force the direction of the wind to change direction.

Comment: @gansub sadly no, that answer is about the regular wind inside a system without fronts passing.

Comment: a front is not some extraordinary phenomenon. It has to obey the NS or primitive equations with some balance condition rolled in.

Comment: So yeah, what is that balance condition? It seems that a front either provides or releases some form of friction to, quite suddenly, change the balance of forces that makes the wind blow in a certain direction. Is it just the boundary between two air masses that provides this resistance?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontogenesis and https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Semigeostrophic_theory

Comment: Mate if a wikipedia article answered my question I wouldn't be here. You seem to know the answer, please walk me through it.

Comment: Looks like your question will be reopened and at that point I expect one of two people to answer it. Or 2/2 maybe.

Answer (score 2):

An answer I got on Reddit which seems to make sense is that fronts are usually accompanied by a pressure change which locally reinforces the "normal" [geostrophic wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostrophic_wind) which changes the wind direction.

If anyone has a more in depth answer I'd love to hear it.